# error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels, in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

[image]

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(DATE= mdy(DATE)) %>%
  select(DATE, GAME_ID, PLAYER_NAME, SUCCESS)%>%
  distinct%>%
  group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>% 
  summarise(Shot_rate = mean(SUCCESS== "made")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Shot_rate>=0.50)

df_mod <- df %>% dplyr::filter(PLAYER_NAME %in% df1$PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  mutate(LOCATION_AWAY = ifelse(LOCATION == "H", 0, 1),
         SUCCESS = ifelse(SUCCESS == "made", 1, 0),
         PERIOD = factor(PERIOD)
         ) %>%
  select(SUCCESS, LOCATION_AWAY,PERIOD,CLOSE_DEF_DIST,SHOT_DIST,SHOT_CLOCK,TOUCH_TIME)

mod <- glm(SUCCESS ~., data = df_mod, family = binomial())
tidy(mod, exponentiate = T) %>%
  kable(digits = 3, align = "c", caption = "Logistic regression model results")
```

I don't know how to do it!

Comment: The top "enter image description here" is the data summary.

Comment: the error is because one of your variables only has one unique level. you need to have at least two to do a logistic regression. also for people to help more you should also post your data set and packages to your question.